# Stripe API using PHP: get all subscribers under a product & OR under a pricing plan

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

Stripe API QUESTIONS:

**Using PHP in the api, how would I do the following:**

A) Get ALL Names, IDs, Emails of all active subscribers under
a product? In this case MM Club?

B) Get ALL Names, IDs, Emails of all active subscribers under
a pricing plan? Example: In this case Fun Club?

SEE IMAGE ATTACHED

[image]

I DID read all over the Stripe Documentation but could find nothing in particular that would solve my issue. I did get some of the vars using this method, but again not what I am looking for.

```
$Var = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_exampleID");

for($i=0;count($Var->subscriptions->data) >$i; $i++ )
{
echo  "__________________<br> Subscribed to: " . $Var->subscriptions->data[$i]->plan->id;
echo  "<br> NAME: " . $Var ->subscriptions->data[$i]->plan->nickname;
$ProdID = $Var ->subscriptions->data[$i]->plan->product;
$VAR2 = \Stripe\Product::retrieve("$ProdID");
echo  "<br> PRODUCT NAME: " . $VAR2->name; 
echo  "<br> Status to: " . $Var ->subscriptions->data[$i]->status;
echo "<br>";
}
```

This outputs what a customer subscribed to and gets:
Name:
Status:
Subscription:
etc..

I need different data and the api docs don't seem to be providing so I thought I would ask someone else who may know.

Comment: The Stripe API documentation is [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php)

Comment: Ok, I can do that. I have tried many things. I will post it. I also read almost the entire document for the api. Thanks for your suggestion tho.